# 'screen' utility : how to prevent it to handle the display?

Tags: gnu-screen

The `screen` program fully controls what's displayed. For example the scrollback buffer is not the one of the terminal.
I don't like the idea to have a separate set of commands, and a separate set of settings for exactly the same goal. This also forbid me to copy/paste 200 line from the scrollback buffer into a text editor, to use the mouse, etc.

Is there a way to tell `screen` to just record what's displayed, and let the terminal do the job ?
Or maybe another program instead of `screen` ?

Comment: Are you just looking for tools like [script](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) and its [scriptreplay](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scriptreplay.1.html) counterpart?

Comment: I agree this is a duplicate. And not workable solution (the given solution is a trick. Still impossible to select 200 lines with the mouse or use scrollbars, and many other things).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternative to `screen` there is always `tmux`. [Main site is here](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

If you don't want screen to buffer the scroll back it's the option:

```
screen -S testsession -h 0
```

or in the `.screenrc` file add the line:

```
defscrollback 0
```

With this option in place I was able to scroll back in my terminal using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

#### EDIT #1

This option most definitely works for me on Fedora 14 with screen version 4.0.3-15 on GNOME 2.32. When I do this I'm in a gnome-terminal window which has the scroll back configured for 3000 lines.

[image: ss of gnome-terminal scrollback]

In my terminal I run the following command:

```
screen -S blahblah -h 0
```

Once in `screen` if I do the typical <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> My window changes to this, but I can't scroll back.

[image: ss of gnome-terminal scrollback w/ screen]

However if I run a find command in this same terminal, I can definitely scrollback using just the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up/Down</kbd> keys:

[image: ss of find scrolled back]

Comment: Sadly don't work at all for me (Debian).